# Удаление sys.stdout.write() Python

Tags: python

Здраствуйте!

Я пытался стереть выводы в консоли `sys.stdout.write()` через `"\r"` и `"\b"`.

Позже использовал `"\f"`, но выводилось `"♀"`, а должно было очистить консоль.

Код:

```py
def UPDATE_FRAME(TEXT:str, STRINGS_WAS:int, NEED_TO_LOG):
                
    global printed
                
    printf('\r'+'\033\r'*STRINGS_WAS + TEXT, 0)
    if NEED_TO_LOG: printed = TEXT.split('\n')
```

printf:

```py
    
def printf(TEXT:str, NEED_TO_LOG):
    global printed
    stdout.write(TEXT)
    if NEED_TO_LOG:
        for take in TEXT.split('\n'): printed.append(take)
```

Comment: В чём вопрос-то? Что-то работает не так, как вы ожидали?

Comment: И вот этим вы что делаете `'\033\r'*STRINGS_WAS`?  Зачем вам `ESC` и снова возврат каретки, да ещё и повторять сколько-то раз,